# YouTube API dynamically loading videos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, youtube-api

-I want many videos loaded onto a page, nothing fancy
-Video ID is stored in a database -> $slide['message']
-I can get it to load only one video.  The others are blank
-It is inside a loop, when the kind == youtube, it tries to put the video in.

```
if($slide['kind'] == 'youtube'){
?>
<li>
<div class="info<?php echo $count+1; ?>">
<h1><?php echo $slide['title']; ?></h1>
<div id="ytplayer<?php echo $count+1; ?>" class="youTube-viewer"></div>
<script>
var video = '<?php echo $slide['message']; ?>';
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer<?php echo $count+1; ?>', {
height: '365',
width: '648',
videoId: video,
playerVars: {
'rel': 0,
'enablejsapi': 1,
}
});
}
</script>
<h2><?php echo $slide['name']; ?></h2>  
</div>
</li>
<?php
}
```

Comment: That code is quite difficult to follow. Is there any way you can stuff it into a jsFiddle and reproduce your problem for us all to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what jlmcdonald gave me as a hint, I got it to work, see the link to the fiddle below
http://jsfiddle.net/AaGvt/

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '250',
    width: '500',
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {}
  });

  player = new YT.Player('player2', {
    height: '250',
    width: '500',
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {}
  });

  player = new YT.Player('player3', {
    height: '250',
    width: '500',
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {}
  });

}

</script>

<div id="player"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
<div id="player3"></div>
```

Through SQL requests and loops you can build the divs

```
<div id="player"></div>
etc...
```

And create the needed javascript

```
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '250',
    width: '500',
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {}
  });
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this whole code block is in a loop, then it is failing because of the loop itself. Let's say you have 4 videos that are to get inserted ... because your code for loading the YT API javascript library is inside the loop, you'll end up loading it 4 times. And because your callback function is inside the loop, you'll end up defining it 4 times, each time overwriting the previous definition as well as overriding the object that references the videos. Since your callback function references the video, then only the last video in your list ever has a callback function that persists, so my guess is it's that video which gets inserted.

tl;dr -- the problem is not in the API but in the programming structure.

Perhaps you could reorganize your code something like this:

```
 // DON'T START YOUR LOOP YET
    <script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    // START YOUR LOOP HERE
<?php
if($slide['kind'] == 'youtube'){
?>
        var player<?php echo $count+1 ?>;
    var video = '<?php echo $slide['message']; ?>';
    player<?php echo $count+1 ?> = new YT.Player('ytplayer<?php echo $count+1; ?>', {
    height: '365',
    width: '648',
    videoId: video,
    playerVars: {
    'rel': 0,
    'enablejsapi': 1,
    }
    }); // CODE CONTINUES ON FROM HERE, EVENTUALLY ENDING THE LOOP, PUTTING IN THE HTML
```

etc. etc. etc. Note that I recognize that my code isn't valid; I'm instead just pointing out that your loop should be inside the onYouTubePlayerAPIReady, and you need to create a separate player object for each of the videos. (Well, you don't need to ... you could employ a different strategy that leverages other aspects of the API ... but this is the easiest given what you have.) As a commenter above pointed out, if you create a jsfiddle with your code, people could much more easily help you fine tune it to put this approach into practice.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, today is the first time I've heard of jsFiddle and I will surely get around to checking it out, it looks like a very useful tool.  Your insight is very helpful.